# Admin panel hangs after login

Tags: admin, cache, session

I am having a issue on my live server, when I try to login to the admin panel it lets me through but then it just hangs and the panel never gets loaded. 
The same code running on my dev instance works fine so I am guessing it is not a code issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "just hangs"?

Comment: Looks like it is about to load the next page but just keeps loading and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` enabled? If not is there anything in your server logs or Magento logs?

Comment: Looked through logs and the admin activities but no hints in there... (and thanks for trying to help! @tim)

Comment: Try to trace out what is being loaded with some debugging tools and see what they provide.  KCacheGrind, New Relic, etc. can all shed some insight.

Comment: Hey, are you sure the url for the admin is valid when you deploy to the live server ? It could be pointing at your local ip or something which is not accessible when it's on the live server (it's a record in `core_config_data` if I recall).

Answer (score 2):

Please check your cookie settings - You can look directly at the MySQL table if needed.

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%cookie%';
```

If you cookie path is set incorrect you will have problems setting an already set cookie.

Check your var folder is writable.

You can test by changing the your local.xml session write area from files to db

The next obvious thing is to clear your cookies in your browser. Chrome will behave this way when moving your site from one domain to another.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing var/session and var/cache and see if that clears your problem.